# How do I get the URL for the request when I get a BadRequestException in Jax-rs?

Tags: jax-rs, java-ee-7, jersey-client

I'm getting a `BadRequestException` when using Jersey 2 and I'd like to get the URL that was used in the request and print it in the logs when the exception is caught.

Is there a property/method combination on the BadRequestException object that will return the URL?  I don't see it in the JavaDocs, but it could have a name unrelated to "URL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get URI from `BadRequestException`. But you can get it from [WebTarget](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html) you invoked the request on:

```
WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://localhost");

try {
    String result = target.request().get(String.class);
} catch (BadRequestException bre) {
    // get the URI
    target.getUri();
}
```

If you don't want to use try-catch block:

```
Response response = target.request().get();

if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
    // OK
} else {
    // Handle other state.
}
```